# Can't import pymatgen.core "No module named 'pymatgen.core'"

Tags: python, import, pymatgen

I've used `pip install pymatgen` with Python 3.9.1 on Windows 10 to install pymatgen, but I'm getting the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\code\pymatgen\pymatgen.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pymatgen.core as mg
      File "D:\code\pymatgen\pymatgen.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pymatgen.core as mg
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymatgen.core'; 'pymatgen' is not a package
```

I have also tried to install the previous 2 versions but still getting the same error though I can already see it in the pip list

```
pymatgen                          2022.3.22
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try using conda ? if this doesn't work then there is definitely some dependencies issue

https://pymatgen.org/installation.html